# Convert object array to string array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to read JSON out of a file and convert it into an array of strings made from the concatenation of two properties.

So far I've got this:

```
 $packageCache = Get-Content $pathtojsonfile | ConvertFrom-Json | %{$($_.Key) + "-" + $($_.Value)}

 Write-Output $packageCache
```

The problem is that it ends up creating an array containing the Id values and Version values as completely different items in the array.

It ends up looking like this:

```
key1
key2
value1
value2
```

What have I got wrong?

**Update:** The JSON looks like this:

```
[{ "Key":"key1", "Value":"value1"},{"Key":"key2", "Value":"value2"}]
```

The expected result is this:

```
key1-value1
key2-value2
```

The code as posted is all there is. Yes, it's part of a script.

Comment: So us a sample JSON to start so we can reproduce the issue in the even it is not obvious

Comment: I can't see how that can be your code, the only outputs that make sense to me would be errors (file doesn't exist, isn't valid JSON, etc.) or strings containing `-`, or at least `-` lines at the end of the output. I have to guess you're working in the shell and didn't run the lines in the same order, or didn't run those exact lines, or you're in a script and one line is in a function in another scope, or something like that...?

Comment: Also you probably want `.Keys` and `.Values` (with 's' at the end), but that doesn't change my previous confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the final pipe bind that is messing you up, just change it to:

```
$json = Get-Content $pathtojsonfile | ConvertFrom-Json
$packageCache = $json |% {"$($_.Key)-$($_.Value)"}
$packageCache
key1-value1
key2-value2
```

Incidentally, I'll also point out that the `+` signs are not necessary, just wrap the whole thing in `"` as shown above.

Comment: I was literally typing up my own answer as yours popped in. I didn't realize that ConvertFrom-Json returns a System.Object[]. This means that I kept iterating over a single Object[]. The one line variation is just to surround the first part with **(** and **)**. Good catch!

Comment: Good point on the 1 line version, should have posted that instead :)

Answer (score 0):

CodedBeard beat me to it, but...

I was totally on the wrong track here. Apparently ConvertFrom-Json retuns an Object[]. So, I was just iterating over the single item and not getting anywhere.

If I unroll the returned array, everything starts to work.

```
($packageCache = Get-Content $pathtojsonfile | ConvertFrom-Json) | %{$($_.Key) + "-" + $($_.Value)}
```

Note the **(** and **)** around the first part of the command.